# Git push failure

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

**I am trying to push to git and am getting this error message**

```
Enumerating objects: 57, done.
Counting objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (41/41), 185.34 MiB | 1.51 MiB/s, done.
Total 41 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have already tried:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But this resulted in a different but similar message:

```
Enumerating objects: 57, done.
Counting objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41/41), 185.34 MiB | 6.38 MiB/s, done.
Total 41 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you are pushing a lot of code that includes binaries. 1) Why does your code has binary files? If it's by mistake then remove them. 2) If allowed then try using SSH to push your code, HTTP has a timeout issue.

Comment: 504 is a "gateway timeout": something somewhere dropped your connection. This isn't related to buffer sizes, but (as @MudassirRazvi said) may well relate to the size of the files in the commits you're sending. You did send a fairly big set of data (185 MB, spread out over 40 internal Git objects). It's not totally absurd (some people put multi-gigabyte files in repositories, which sites like GitHub reject) but it's unusually large.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem which was pointed out above was that I was trying to commit to much.

I ran:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Which removes the previous commits, I then committed and pushed smaller changes.

Comment: I´m glad you fixed your issue, please accept your answer so other people who face this issue can find it easy

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting too much, you can increase the http buffer size:

`git config --global http.postBuffer 120000000 (~120MB)`